# Draw a letter without Glyph using UIBezierPath

Tags: core-graphics, uibezierpath

I want to draw letters using `UIBezierPath`. I've found a [tutorial here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/iPhone/Glyph.aspx). However, it gives me a closed path representing the outline of the letter, as shown below. I want a path representing the body of the letter.

How can this be made a single line representing the body?

[image: Character]

Comment: Your question is not very clear.  I understand that English is probably not your native language.  Please edit your question.  Try to add more details about what you want to do and what is wrong with the tutorial.

Comment: Do you mean that, rather than the line tracing *outline* of the glyph, you want the a line that traces the body of the glyph?

Comment: Yes @AdamWright I want path of character be only a single line, not outline.

Comment: @PhamTuyen: I don't know if that helps, but *filling* the path instead of *stroking* it would paint the glyph "body".

Answer (score 1):

In general, glyphs in modern typefaces are not "lines" in the sense you're talking about. They're outlines. To see why, think about any serif face, like Times. How would the serifs be expressed as a single line?

That said, there is a special class of type faces, colloquially referred to as "stick fonts" that *are* based on lines, and are often used for CNC engraving. Here is a resource: [CamBam Stick Fonts](http://www.mrrace.com/CamBam_Fonts/) Perhaps that will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

As you've found, Core Text can provide only a glyph outline. Asking for a "single line" for a glyph is a bit ambiguous; consider the letter `i` - what single line would represent it? Moreover, a single line cannot encode the varying width information within a glyph.

There are methods for closed bezier paths by which you can compute the a path representing some notion of the "centre". I can't recall them off the top of my head. However, if you want to draw the glyphs, you can do it with just the outline; use `CGContextFillPath` to draw a the filled glyph (assuming your context has a set fill colour).